# Spring Batch (modular=true) creates job config beans twice

Tags: java, spring-batch

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular=true)
public class ModularJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory job() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(FlatfileToDbJobConfiguration.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory anotherJob() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(FlatfileToDbJobAnotherConfiguration.class);
    }

}
```

For example show only one config, another like this.

```
@Configuration
public class FlatfileToDbJobConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilders;

        @Autowired
        private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders;

        @Bean
        public Job flatfileToDbJob(){
            return jobBuilders.get("flatfileToDbJob")
                    .listener(protocolListener())
                    .start(step())
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step step(){
            return stepBuilders.get("step")
                    .<Partner,Partner>chunk(1)
                    .reader(reader())
                    .processor(processor())
                    .writer(writer())
                    .build();
        }

        // ...
        // rest part of code
        // ...
}
```

All works fine, but all beans methods in config files call twice. I think, first in common context and second in individual. Is it normal? I can't use post construct, because it will call twice. How to have modular=true and only one bean initialization? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer. I need @Lazy initialization. Then config will initialize then individual context creates.

```
@Configuration
@Lazy
public class FlatfileToDbJobConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilders;

        @Autowired
        private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders;

        @Bean
        public Job flatfileToDbJob(){
            return jobBuilders.get("flatfileToDbJob")
                    .listener(protocolListener())
                    .start(step())
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step step(){
            return stepBuilders.get("step")
                    .<Partner,Partner>chunk(1)
                    .reader(reader())
                    .processor(processor())
                    .writer(writer())
                    .build();
        }

        // ...
        // rest part of code
        // ...
}
```